# finding intersection of a parametrical representation

Tags: vectors, parametrization

[image]

I've managed to answer the question and get S = 3, so by substituting S into L the intersection point is (11 6), but what I'm confused about is, when I substitute S into L' to double check my answer I get (8 3), shouldn't they be the same.

Comment: Do not replace $ s=3 $  in the L' equations. the intersection point corresponds to another s, if you use L'.

Comment: You should use another symbol for parameter in $L'$ to find intersection: $\left(\begin{array}{}2\\3\end{array}\right)+s\left(\begin{array}{}3\\1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{}5\\0\end{array}\right)+t\left(\begin{array}{}1\\1\end{array}\right)$.